# Uncaught TypeError when I click on mobile menu icon - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, responsive

I'm doing this website: https://marco95op.github.io/sunnyside-agency-landing-page-main/
I've done only the mobile part so use the responsive tool to see, the problem is my menu doesn't work with the snippet code I wrote in js:

```js
"use strict";

const hamburgerIcon = document.querySelector(".hamburger-icon");
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links");
const nav = document.querySelector("navbar");

hamburgerIcon.addEventListener("click", () =>{
   nav.classList.toggle("active");
});

navLinks.forEach(function (nav){
    nav.addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log(this);
    });
});
```

```css
.nav-links.active{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<img class ="hamburger-icon" src="./images/icon-hamburger.svg" alt="hamburger">
      
      <nav id="navbar">
          <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li> 
            <li><button><a href="#">Contact</a></button></li> 
          </ul>
      </nav>
```

Here's the repo: https://github.com/marco95OP/sunnyside-agency-landing-page-main.git

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: [doesn't work](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) isn't a useful description of the problem

Answer (score 0):

## querySelector()

- `querySelector()` is use to select element you need to mention id `#` and class `.` and name.
- `.active` class add than `display:flex;` and else `display:none;`.

### What is Problems in code

- `document.querySelector("nav-links");` to `document.querySelector("#navbar");` specify id and select right element.
- in css add `#navbar{display: none;}`. if element not have `.active` class than display none.

```js
const hamburgerIcon = document.querySelector(".hamburger-icon");
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links");
const nav = document.querySelector("#navbar");

hamburgerIcon.addEventListener("click", () =>{
   nav.classList.toggle("active");
});

navLinks.forEach(function (nav){
    nav.addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log(this);
    });
});
```

```css
    
   #navbar.active{
      display: block;
  }#navbar{display: none;}
```

```html
<img class="hamburger-icon" src="./images/icon-hamburger.svg" alt="hamburger">
      
      <nav id="navbar">
          <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li> 
            <li><button><a href="#">Contact</a></button></li> 
          </ul>
      </nav>
```